# Airflow pipeline is not triggered

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, pipeline

Actually I've defined a pipeline start date from 12 Dec 2021. This is same as 4 am Singapore time on 13 Dec 2021. As by default the pipeline is in utc, I've set it to 8 pm utc i.e., 4 am sgt The pipeline seems to not trigger at 4 am singapore time,, I don't under stand why the pipeline is not triggered? Below is the dag config

```
dag = DAG(
    'test',
    start_date=datetime.datetime(year=2021,month=12,day=12),
    schedule_interval='0 20 * * *'
)
```

Comment: Could you try changing the start date to a few days back, and see if it gets triggered?

Comment: yes it works that way. I am interested to understand why it didn't trigger on the scheduled date. If I change the start date to 1 day back. it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the start date to a few days back, and it will get triggered.

The reason is that the `start_date` specifies the first date and time for which you want to have data in a database. Airflow will run a job at `start_date + interval`, so after the interval has passed (because that’s when data becomes available). You can read more about it [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html) and [here](https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/gotchas.html).